# Identifying similar and crossing lines in the same layer

Tags: postgis

I have a single layer that contains similar geometry that may or may not cross, that is a result of imported geometry having a slightly different position.  I need to identify the geometry that is close (i.e. within 5m) or cross; below is an example of the data. This is showing data in the same layer, I have just displayed the problematic geometry in red which I need to identify.

[image]

I have a PostGIS solution for the geometry that crosses (B), which is shown below.

```
select row_number() over() as qgisid, a.geom as geom
from roads a inner join roads b
on st_crosses(a.geom, b.geom)
```

However, I am struggling to find a method for geometry that is very close to other geometry within the same layer (A).  Does anyone have any ideas on how to identify geometry similar to that marked as A?

Comment: I think [ST_HausdoffDistance](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_HausdorffDistance.html) might be what you are looking for. It is a bit hard to wrap your head round, but it measures simlilarities between geometries, which I think is what you are asking?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ST_DWithin` and specify the distance.

```
SELECT *
FROM roads AS a
INNER JOIN roads AS b
  ON ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 50);
```

That 50 is in meters if you're on SRID4326.

See [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) for more information.

You may want to only use this if the row doesn't otherwise `ST_Crosses` with something else.